# Attribute error in inherited view?

Tags: python, inheritance, view, python-3.x, odoo

I added a new module that depends on base module, and my model inherits res.partner, i need to add two fields: customer reference and reference type, i did that the way it should be but there is an error that has really irritated me. The error is: AttributeError: View definition error for inherited view 'reference.customer_reference_form' on model 'res.partner': Element '' not found in parent view '%(parent_xml_id)s'.

Comment: without your seeing code its impossible to solve error, but seeing your error it said the you try to add field after other field in main modules but it does not exits in main

Comment: Hello, can u paste a small snippet of your code so that we can identify problem.